# Router context is empty in Router Component render function on second use

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

#### Problem

Framework7 Router Component `render` function does not have context after you use the link second time. This bug first appeared in `2.0.10` and not fixed in `2.1.2`

#### Reproduction

Click on 'About' link. Click 'back' link. Click 'about' link again. Not working example alerts 'undefined' starting from second time you click 'about' link.

JSFiddle:

- [Working on 2.0.6](https://jsfiddle.net/cngxn7rz/)
- [Not working on 2.1.2](https://jsfiddle.net/p9eL1pum/8/)

I tried to debug to make a workaround but couldn't understand how this context is attached even at first time. Would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: What browser does your 2.0.6 work in?  Your 'working' fiddle does nothing at all in Chrome 65.

Comment: Google 64, latest Safari. there is `alert` function call - are you sure it is not blocked at your browser?

Comment: Hmm, console says this: `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
    at new i (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/framework7/2.0.6/js/framework7.min.js:12:70379)
    at window.onload (https://fiddle.jshell.net/cngxn7rz/show/:57:11)`

Comment: ...it runs the 2.1.2 fiddle OK, but the issue you are asking about is present, too.  When I said 'does nothing at all' I mean no content at all, just a white screen, nothing to see, nothing to click.  (That's JavaScript frameworks for ya!)

Answer (score 0):

They just reacted to my issue and provided a [fix](https://github.com/framework7io/framework7/commit/143a45b9cc22d5d53d022f30264109bf82c29aaf), hope to see it released in 2.1.3